# radio button happen only on a button click android studio

Tags: android

Essentially, what I want is that once I click the Translate button, I want to print which radio button is currently checked. What I have right now is that as soon as I click a radio button, it prints it to the textview, but I want it to only happen once I click the Translate button. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void Translate(View view) {
        onRadioButtonClicked(view);

    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_hi:
                if (checked) { display("hi"); }
                break;
            case R.id.radio_bus:
                if (checked) { display("bus"); }
                break;
            case R.id.radio_bathroom:
                if (checked) { display("bathroom"); }
                break;
            case R.id.radio_beer:
                if (checked) { display("beer"); }
                break;
            case R.id.radio_cost:
                if (checked) { display("cost"); }
                break;
            default:
                display("no button clicked");
        }
    }



    private void display(String str) {
        TextView translateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        translateTextView.setText(str);
    }
}







    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Translate"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="Translate"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_hi"
            android:text="@string/hi"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_bus"
            android:text="@string/taxi"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_bathroom"
            android:text="@string/bathroom"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_beer"
            android:text="@string/beer"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio_cost"
            android:text="@string/cost"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm am not 100% sure if I understood you question/code.
But if you just want to change the text on Translate Button Click you can try something like this:

```
public void Translate(View view) {

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);


        int btnID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        //display the String based on the Radio Button ID
        switch (btnID) {
        case R.id.radio_hi:
            if (checked) { display("hi"); }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_bus:
            if (checked) { display("bus"); }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_bathroom:
            if (checked) { display("bathroom"); }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_beer:
            if (checked) { display("beer"); }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_cost:
            if (checked) { display("cost"); }
            break;
        default:
            display("no button clicked");
    }
 }
```

basically it just uses the currently check radio btn ID to determine what should be printed in the TextView.

Just take a look at `getCheckedRadioButtonId` this function might solve your problems.

Also remove the onRadioButtonClicked calls in the Radio Buttons.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm not sure why the check doesn't work but if you remove the if (checked), and go directly to just display(whatever), it works.